# Does restoring a backup of IIS6 restore the GAC?

Tags: iis-6, backup, windows-server-2003, gac, restore

I was wondering: if I have some DLLs in the GAC - will they get restored if I restore a backup of IIS6 on a fresh Windows 2003 box?

Or will I need to backup/rebuild the GAC separately from IIS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, assemblies in the GAC will not be backed up by an IIS backup.  You will need to re-install your assemblies into the GAC.